# How to change ui-view template URL programatically

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to change the `ui-view` `templateUrl` programatically from inside a controller because the `templateUrl` option does not support injection of services and I need a service to determine the template URL.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the docs for `templateProvider` here:
["Quick Reference - template, templateUrl, templateProvider"](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#template-templateurl-templateprovider), *Github - angular-ui/ui-router*

Comment: How can I change it from JS though? In the templateProvider I can only inject constants and providers. I can't inject services which I need to determine URL.

Comment: `templateProvider: function(serviceName) { return serviceName.doWhatever(); }`

Comment: You can't inject services in providers, can you?

Comment: `templateProvider` is a provider for the template path. It accepts normal injectable services.

Comment: Hm, I checked that before posing and it failed, but it might have been for other reasons. I'll give that a try, thank you.

Comment: Now I remember, the problem with `templateProvider` is that it returns HTML string instead of URL. I need to construct a URL, not HTML.

Comment: So inject `$http` and load a template.

Comment: I thought of AJAX of course, but that's more of a workaround I'd say.

Comment: I don't see how it makes any sense to consider that a 'workaround' when [that's exactly what `$templateFactory` does anyway](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/src/templateFactory.js#L85).

Comment: Well, as I see it, if there's a `template` and a `templateProvider`, there should be a `templateUrl` and a `templateUrlProvider`. However, yours is the best solution from what I've been able to read. Please add that to your answer (i.e. using `$http` to return a URL) so I can mark it as correct. Thank you.