# Change ui-view template without changing URL

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following states configuration (simplified):

```
$stateProvider
  .state(
    'showitem', 
     { url: '/item/{id}', templateUrl: 'showitem.html', controller: 'MyCtrl' }
  )
  .state(
    'notFound',
    { url: '^*path', templateUrl: '404.html'}
  );
```

When I enter `/badurl`, 404 error is shown as expected.

When I enter `/item/123`, the application's API is being queried for item with specified identifier. It returns item data on success or 404 HTTP header if the item could not be found. In order to detect such errors globally, I wrote a http interceptor:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $location) {
  return {
    responseError: function(rejection) {
      if(rejection.status == 404)
        $location.path('/404');
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  };
});
```

Code works but when the item's id is wrong, the `/item/123` URL changes to `/404` which shows an error page.

Question is - how to load the `404.html` view into my `<div ui-view></div>` element **without** changing the URL?

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497970/how-to-change-ui-view-template-url-programatically) but the templateProvider does not seem to address my problem.

Comment: Please, try to check this [approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25591908/1679310)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25591908/878514) and @RadimKohler comment. Remove `url` from `notFound` route:

```
$stateProvider
.state(
  'showitem', 
  { url: '/item/{id}', templateUrl: 'showitem.html', controller: 'MyCtrl' }
)
.state(
  'notFound',
  { templateUrl: '404.html'}
);
```

Configure `oterwise` rule:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location) {
  var $state = $injector.get('$state');
  $state.go('notFound');
  return $location.path();
});
```

And finally, go to the `notFound` route on 404 API error:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, $injector) {
  return {
    responseError: function(rejection) {
      if(rejection.status == 404)
        $injector.get('$state').go('notFound');
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Anyway of doing this without ui-router ? I meanusing angular $routeProvider